# Why does count(distinct ..) return different values on the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select count(distinct a,b,c,d) from mytable;
select count(distinct concat(a,'-',b),concat(c,'-',d)) from mytable;
```

Since '-' never appears in a,b,c,d fields, the 2 queries above should return the same result. Am I right ?

Actually it is not the case, the difference is 4 rows out of ~60M and I cant figure out how this is possible

Any idea or example ?
Thanks

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using (your syntax only works in one of the databases you originally tagged it with anyway).

Comment: What types are a, b, c, d?

Comment: @MatBailie . . . `COUNT(DISTINCT)` (in MySQL, which is the only database where the syntax works) returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.

Comment: no null values, a c are unsigned int, b d are varchar

Comment: If this question were tagged correctly, I would definitely upvote it.

Comment: It's going to be important to know exactly which DBMS you are using.

Comment: if @Gordon agrees to put back the mysql tag that might help you then

Comment: @guigoz: you need to decide that: which DBMS **are** you using?

Comment: @giogoz - Pick ***ONE*** please.  MySQL ***or*** Oracle ***or*** PostgreSQL.

Comment: once again : mysql

Answer (score 1):

First, I am assuming that you are using MySQL, because that is the only database of your original tags where your syntax would be accepted.

Second, this does not directly answer your question.  Given your types and expressions, I do not see how you can get different results.  However, very similar constructs can produce different results.

It is very important to note that `NULL` is not the culprit.  If any argument is `NULL` for either `COUNT(DISTINCT)` or `CONCAT()`, then the result is `NULL` -- and `NULL`s are not counted.

However, spaces at the end of strings can be an issue.  Consider the results from this query:

```
select count(distinct x, y),
       count(distinct concat(x, '-', y)), 
       count(distinct concat(y, '-', x))
from (select 1 as x, 'a' as y union all
      select 1, 'a ' union all
      select 1, NULL
     ) a
```

I would expect the second and third arguments to return the same thing.  But spaces at the end of the string cause differences.  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` ignores them.  However, `CONCAT()` will embed them in the string.  Hence, the above returns

```
1     1     2
```

And the two values are different.

In other words, two values may not be exactly the same, but `COUNT(DISTINCT)` might regard them as the same.  Spaces are one example.  Collations are another potential culprit.

Comment: Note that HSQLDB also supports `count(distinct a,b)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . It was not one of the original tags ;)  But I note that it also supports `concat()` so the syntax would work in that database.

Comment: I know - just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Take example of sample data

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
1   2   5   7
1   2   5   7
1   3   3   4
1   3   3   4
```

then count (distinct (a, b, c, d)) = 4

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
1   2   5   7
1   3   3   4
```

and count (distinct (a,-,b), distinct (c,-,d)) = 3

```
dist (a,-,b)        dist (c,-,d)    
1   2               3   4
5   6               7   8
1   3               5   7
```

Comment: Assuming MySQL, that's not the problem : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e6796/1

Comment: (1 2),(5 7) is missing => count = 4

Comment: I haven't executed query. Logically i think it should give 3 based on below explanation.
dist (a,-,b) = 3 (1-2, 5-6, 1-3)
dist (c,-,d) = 3 (3-4, 7-8, 5-7)
now  count(distinct concat(a,'-',b),concat(c,'-',d)) should be 3